# C# Directory Service: How to get sub groups of groups in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

How do I get sub groups from the Groups using directory service.

Assuming I have the following groups in AD:

```
Master Group
     Group 1
     Group 2
```

I want to get all groups that belong to Master Group. So in my case I want to get a list that contains Group 1 and Group 2

Here is part of my code:

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomain.COM"))
{
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "Master Group");
    var results = group.Group();// returns nothing
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Group(bool)` method in `GroupPrincipal`.
I guess you mean the GetMembers(bool) method?

When `true` is passed to `GetMembers` all the child groups are skipped (it returns only leaf objects like the users or computers).

You may pass a `false` instead and filter out all non-group members. But this means you only get the direct member groups and need to have some way to get all the nested member groups (e.g. a recursive method).